# error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]|

Tags: c

I am trying to get from the while loop the counter value to the main block.
  everything worked fine until I got the counter integer involved and now I'm getting this error:

```
"error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]|"
```

What do I need to do to fix it? I want to get the counter value from the function into the main block to  use it and print the actual value of it.

Thanks!

```
      int ScanFunction(char array[ThirtyOne] , int counter){
    PrintEnterMessage();
    for(int i=0 ; i < ThirtyTwo ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c" , &array[i]);
        counter++;
        if(array[i] == Fourtynine || array[i] == Fourtyeight) array[i] = array[i] - '0'; // This is to convert the numbers from char to int
        if(array[i] == Excmark)
            {
            array[i] = 0;
            return counter;
            }
    }

    }

    int main(){
    char array[ThirtyOne] = {0};
    int counter = -1;
    ScanFunction(array, counter);
    printf("%d, counter is: %d" , array[1], counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at what happens when the `for` loop ends ... no `return XXX;` Not that you use its return value, but the compiler lets you know anyway. Note that it won't change the value of `counter` in `main` which will still be `-1`.

Comment: `ThirtyOne`, `Fortynine`, `Excmark` ... no, just say no! Either use `31`, `49`, `'!'` or relevant names (something like): `LOWER_LIMIT`, `DEFAULT_VALUE`, `STOP_SYMBOL` (I didn't try to understand the reason for the values from your code, so the names I chose are arbitrary and possibly worse than using the values directly).

Comment: Yeah Im using ThirtyOne and Excmark and etc.. because thats what I was asked for in the university.. they have a program that checks our program which cant read numbers besides 0 1 so they ask us to do so.. anyway its irrelevant.


btw for the first comment, I moved the return out side of the for loop and it doesnt show me the error anymore, but I do not get back the value of counter to the main block. how can I get it to the main block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScanFunction()` promises to return an `int` and it does so only if the second `if` block after `if(array[i] == Excmark)` gets hit.  You need to add some other `return` at the end of the function, in order to return a value in the case that the `if` block is not reached.

Additionally, you do nothing with the value that gets returned by `ScanFunction()`.  You need to assign some variable to the output of the function, such as:

```
counter = ScanFunction(array, counter);
```